# Android crash on one activity delegates to previous activity

Tags: android

I have two activities, first one is LoginActivity, the second one is MainActivity. When an error occurs on MainActivity I get force close dialog which is ok, but why does my app goes to previous activity and runs some code on it and then I get another force close?

Shouldn't app close immediately when error occurs on particular activity, instead of after crashing on MainActivity I see in log that it executes some code on LoginActivity as well and if not not properly handled, it crashes there too so whenever I get an error on MainActivity it triggers one more force close dialog on LoginActivity?

Comment: `I get force close dialog which is ok`???

Comment: your `MainActivity` is closed, therefore the `LoginActivity` is resumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect the user experience to be? What if they press the back key?

When an Activity crashes the app opens the last Activity that was running as it's at the top of the activity stack. So what you're experiencing is expected behaviour. But you weren't expecting it so it seems you may have structured the flow of your app incorrectly.

When the user starts your app they should be presented with the main activity, when they try to log in they should be presented with the login activity, once login is complete the login activity should be finished so it does not remain in the activity stack.

If you do not finish the login activity and instead start the main activity then the user will be able to press the back key to return to the login activity which is not ideal, as they are already logged in.